# Playing sounds in Python without external module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, tkinter, audio-streaming

I've searched for this around, and every answer seems to include an *external* Python library, such as `Pygame`, `Snack`, etc, for playing sounds.

Is there not a simple pure pythonic way from the built in modules to play, say, a `.wav` file without the use for external modules? I know that `Python` doesn't natively support `.mp3` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most I've found in that regard is [`winsound`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/winsound.html). Nothing extra to install; just import it. However, as you might have guessed, it only works on Windows. I use Pygame's [`mixer`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html) when I want sound. Its support for mp3 files is limited, and it requires an installation (unless you package your application), but it's the most straightforward of the third-party audio modules I've looked into.

Comment: When you say package your application you mean including the pygame module when compiling correct?

Comment: I meant in something that wraps up your application for use on machines lacking even an installation of Python. I use [`cx_freeze`](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) for this.

Comment: I agree pygame's mixer is a simple way to play sound.  Here's a link with an example https://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/61730/sound-with-tkinter